# The sentence in bold below, in the book "The Standard Library" by Nocolai Josuttis, is not clear to me

Tags: c++, c++11, standard-library

I'm reading "The Standard Library", second edition, by Nicolai Josuttis. In its page 183 we have:

> **Examples of Using Unordered Maps and Multimaps**
>
> The example presented for multimaps on page 179 also works for an
>   unordered multimap if you replace `map` by `unordered_map` in the
>   include directive and `multimap` by `unordered_multimap` in the
>   declaration of the container:
>
> ```
> #include <unordered_map>
> ...
> unordered_multimap<int,string> coll;
> ...
> ```
>
> The only difference is that the order of the elements is undefined.
>   **However, on most platforms, the elements will still be sorted because as a default hash function, the modulo operator is used.**

I emphasized in bold the part that is not clear to me. My first impression when I read this was that the author is saying that both programs (the one in page 179, see below) and the one above) should print the name of the cities in the same order on most platforms. But this doesn't happen in clang and GCC. See live examples for [`map`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9b9acc88bd62659) and [`unordered_map`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a320991d7ae7c23f) in GCC. The same results are obtained in clang.

After thinking for a while I interpreted the author as saying that the names of the cities are printed in the same order for almost all platforms, when processed with a `unordered_map`, and the output seems to confirm this. But even so, it's difficult for me to accept this interpretation, as different implementations will probably use different hash functions!

Below, you'll find the example in page 179 referred to above:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    multimap<int,string> coll; // container for int/string values
    // insert some elements in arbitrary order
    // - a value with key 1 gets inserted twice
    coll = { {5,"tagged"},
             {2,"a"},
             {1,"this"},
             {4,"of"},
             {6,"strings"},
             {1,"is"},
             {3,"multimap"} };
    // print all element values
    // - element member second is the value
    for (auto elem : coll) {
        cout << elem.second << ’ ’;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Not very clear what is your actual question.

Comment: all implementations **must** use `http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash` to get a number out of the key. The only implementation left to compilers is how you bring this number in the range `0 - hash-number-of-buckets - 1`. Allmost all implementations use modulo `%` to do this as it is the simplest and does not have have negative impact if the original `hash` function is uniform distributed which `std::hash` is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's at best unhelpful.

The common default hash function for `int` is to use the `int` itself without change.
So if the hash-table has more buckets than the largest integer and duplicates are added in the same order most implementations will (by accident) output the pairs in sorted order.

However in general for objects with some ordering it is not the case that H(A) < H(B) if A < B. H(.) being the hash function.
It's also not generally the case that MAX(H(X)) <= the bucket count.

So the book is really pointing out features of a rather contrived special case.
Why do I think that's unhelpful? 
Presenting accidental properties of contrived special cases may accidentally lead readers to think that they're examples of some wider feature.

The entries in hash maps do not come back in any useful order.
They do not come back in insertion order. They do not come back in reverse insertion order. They do not come back in sorted order. They do not come back in any order. [Sam I am].

If an example is worthwhile it would be an example of them not coming back ordered.

Comment: I think the book is trying to point out that just because you might get ordered values in a simple example of trying `unordered_map`, it doesn't mean you can rely on it.

Comment: `The common default hash function for int is to use the int itself without change. So if the hash-table has more buckets than the largest integer and duplicates are added in the same order most implementations will (by accident) output the pairs in sorted order.` But the example doesn't hash integers, but pairs of <int, string>? Am I missing something?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil only the key i.e. `int` is hashed.

Comment: @bolov Could you give me a quote from the Standard confirming this?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil the whole idea of the `map` is that you have a pair of `key-value`. The value is what it is "useful", the key is how you find the value. You can see this as: `key=position` `value=well.. value`. It makes no sense whatsoever to hash the value.

Comment: @bolov I've just found the quote. It's in [unord.req]/3 in C++14. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that we are talking about 2 hash functions.

The first one is the function which gets a number out of the key. This is by default [std::hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), but can also be provided as a parameter to `std::unorderded_map`.

The other function is the one which takes this number and returns the bucket index, that is takes this number and returns a number in the range `0 - bucket_count() - 1`. This one is implementation defined, but it is almost always modulo `%` as  this as it is the simplest and does not have have negative impact if the original hash function is uniform distributed which `std::hash` is and the user defined is supposed to be.

Comment: There is also implementation freedom in how `std::hash<int>` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is nonsense. On certain platforms, under specific circumstances, the order of elements in a (typically small) `unordered_multimap` will be the same as in a `multimap`. However, what's actually useful to a programmer is a guarantee, such as "This container is sorted". This is guaranteed for neither `unordered_(multi)map` nor `unordered_(multi)set`. The one actually useful ordering guarantee of the unordered associative containers that support equivalent keys (to use terms from the standard) is that entries with equivalent key are always adjacent, e.g. AACBBBD or BBBAADC are valid orders, but ABACBBD is not. This is the reason these containers support the `equal_range` operation like their sorted cousins. Even then (in C++11), `multimap` has a stronger guarantee for these entries because they are not only adjacent, but also appear in order of insertion, which may not be the case for `unordered_multimap`. In fact, for performance reasons, they may appear in reverse order of insertion. But don't rely on that either…